# Permission denied when other users create files

Tags: permissions, home-directory, chmod

I have messed up my home directory. I'm using `dash` as my shell and by myself I can create files just fine, but others can't. I don't think that made sense as it's kind of hard to explain, so hopefully this can enlighten you:

```
alex@ubuntu:~$ ls -l 
total 4
drwxrwxrwx 2 alex www-data 4096 Sep 21 17:55 public_html
alex@ubuntu:~$ git clone git://github.com/twitter/bootstrap
fatal: Could not switch to 'bootstrap': Permission denied
alex@ubuntu:~$ chmod 777 .
alex@ubuntu:~$ git clone git://github.com/twitter/bootstrap
fatal: destination path 'bootstrap' already exists and is not an empty directory.
alex@ubuntu:~$ rm -rf bootstrap
alex@ubuntu:~$ git clone git://github.com/twitter/bootstrap
fatal: Could not switch to 'bootstrap': Permission denied
alex@ubuntu:~$ chmod -R 777 *
alex@ubuntu:~$ git clone git://github.com/twitter/bootstrap
Cloning into 'bootstrap'...
/home/alex/bootstrap/.git/refs: Permission denied
alex@ubuntu:~$ ls -l ..
total 4
drwxrwxrwx 3 alex alex 4096 Sep 21 18:07 alex
alex@ubuntu:~$
```

Not sure what I've done wrong or if it relates to my umask, but any advice is welcome. Thanks!

Comment: It think, this problem more related with git rather that with home directory and permission settings. git has specific permission settings as far as I know

Comment: It's not only git. If I add files to my `public_html` and try view them in my browser, I get a 403 unless I chmod it to 777.

Comment: try putting the file directly into home directory and view it in browser. what happen?

Comment: That won't work; the document root in my Apache config is the public_html folder. It's set to 777 anyway, as is my home directory.

Answer (score 1):

You must use sudo  before the commands